# How to get the links to exercises from quizlet textbook pages using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

Consider this, for example:

https://quizlet.com/explanations/textbook-solutions/linear-algebra-done-right-3rd-edition-9783319110790

My first thought was to click on each of the chapter things to expand and show the exercises. Here's what I came up with:

```py
driver.get("https://quizlet.com/explanations/textbook-solutions/linear-algebra-done-right-3rd-edition-9783319110790")
urls = []

for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.c1tlcqh7 > div.cnuw08l > button"))):
    element.click()

for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.e1tk5ihi > span > a"))):
    urls.append(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

But each chapter has multiple sections.
[image: screenshot of expanded chapter]
My program can only get the exercise links from the first section of each chapter. To get the links to all of the exercises, I will need to click on the other section things too but I haven't been able to work out a system to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To get all link you can implement 2 loops.
In the first loop you scroll to chapter, click on it and get opened container.
In container you get paragraphs list and filter then for visibility.

Then you loop through paragraphs, click on it and get only visible links. So you would get corresponding links for each paragraphs.

After that you click on chapter again to close it and wait for first visible paragraph invisibility if any. (for stableness)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://quizlet.com/explanations/textbook-solutions/linear-algebra-done-right-3rd-edition-9783319110790')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
chapters = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid*=ChapterLink]")))
action_chans = ActionChains(driver)
for chapter in chapters:
    action_chans.scroll_to_element(chapter).perform()
    print(chapter.text)
    chapter.click()
    chapter_container = chapter.find_element(By.XPATH, '../following-sibling::*')
    wait = WebDriverWait(chapter_container, 10)
    paragraphs = chapter_container.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'TextbookTableOfContentsList--link')]")
    visible_paragraphs = [element for element in paragraphs if element.is_displayed()]
    for paragraph in visible_paragraphs:
        print(paragraph.text)
        print('___________________________')
        paragraph.click()
        links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.AssemblyLink')))
        visible_links = [element for element in links if element.is_displayed()]
        for link in links:
            print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    chapter.click()
    if len(visible_paragraphs) > 0:
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(visible_paragraphs[0]))
```